# Using C# Linq to query nested objects

Tags: c#, powershell

I have a PowerShell object and I want to filter the results.

```
public Collection<PSObject> Groups;
```

I have successfully achieved this using linq if I need to filter based on a direct member. But what if I want to filter based on an object 1 or 2 levels deep?

Here is the linq query to filter on a direct member:

```
var groupMembershipFilter = (dynamic)CsQ.Groups.Where(x => x.Members["AgentsByUri"].Value != null).ToList();
```

However I need to drill down another level. In PowerShell this would be easy:

```
$x.AgentsByUri.AbsoluteUri
```

I have tried all sorts but cant figure out how to make this work. So that you can better understand the object structure here are a couple of screen shots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

From the above screen shots you can see the "AgentsByUri" is a collection. Inside that collection I want to test if the property "AbsoluteUri" contains a certain string value.

The other thing I dont understand is why I have to use "Members" and cant just use "BaseObject" - this structure look far more similar to PowerShell and would be my preference if possible as it translates better to my PowerShell brain.

Excuse my terminology, I'm reasonably new to C#! Hopefully this makes sense :)

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var groupMembershipFilter = (dynamic)CsQ.Groups.Where(x => x.Members["AgentsByUri"].Any(x => x.AbsoluteUri == "url")).ToList();
```

Comment: Cheers for this, didnt seem to like the Any bit. I have made a bit of progress and posted a new question here as I think this one may be overly confusing - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511346/using-linq-to-query-nested-objects