# Using Linq to query nested dynamic objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have used the following linq query to access the member Names. The following successfully returns all member Name values within the collection.

```
var we = CsQ.Groups.SelectMany(g => g.Members).Where(a => a.Name == "Name").Select(b => b.Value).ToList();
```

I want to now filter this down based another property within "Members" called AbsoluteUri which is nested in a property AgentsByUri. This doesnt work but gives an idea of the structure:

```
var uri = CsQ.Groups.SelectMany(g => g.Members).Where(a => a.Name == "AgentsByUri").Select(b => b.Value).//??? I NEED TO NOW ACCESS "AbsoluteUri"
```

How can I combine these in to one query so that I can return only the "Names" that have an "AbsoluteUri" that contains "SomeValue". AbsoluteUri seems to be nested in a collection thats nested in AgentsByUri which adds to the complication.

You can see the structure of the AgentsByUri object here - [Using C# Linq to query nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455122/using-c-sharp-linq-to-query-nested-objects)

Excuse my terminology, I'm reasonably new to C#! Hopefully this makes sense :)

Any help or guidance VERY appreciate :)

**EDIT3**
Getting somewhere! Casting as dynamic partially working - member.AgentsByUri is now OK, just cant figure out how to make it apply to the rest of the query. Tried adding in various locations by no luck.

[image: Cast as dynamic]

**EDIT2**
Thanks for everyone's input. I haven't had any further success. I think the biggest problem is that I am dealing with a PowerShell object which is dynamically generated at run time. As a result I cannot access the classes/object because the compiler doesn't yet no about them. To get around this I use the "dynamic" type which allows the compiler to trust that what I provide will be valid at run time. Can I cast as dynamic in a linq query? Or do I need to go about this in a different way?

Heres what I get with the examples give:

[image: Compiler error when trying to access dynamic object]

**EDIT1** (click and zoom, image is high res):
[image: Data Structures]

Comment: Can you please clarify the classes structures? the pictures on the linked answer are small and blurry

Comment: Linq doesn't do recursion.  Create a recursive function and put the Linq inside the recusive function.

Comment: Just include the classes in your question. As code, not as images. Nobody likes to give answers based on incomplete information.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, really appreciate it. A few of you wanted some clarity around the data I am working with. I have updated the post with an image that should show you this.

Comment: Sorry, this really doesn't work. Why don't you capture the dynamic type in a structure of named types, if only for the sake of showing it here?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean or how to do it - any link that I can read up on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just writing this down, based on the image you provided. However, I can not check for correctness without the surrounding code, so no guarantees.

```
var uri = CsQ.Groups
    .SelectMany(g => g.Members)
    .Where(m => m.AgentsByUri.SelectMany(a => a.Value, (a, v) => v.AbsoluteUri).Contains("SomeValue"))
    .Select(b => b.Value)
```

In LINQ syntax it should be much clearer

```
var uri =
    from group in CsQ.Groups
    from dynamic member in group.Members
    where
        (from agent in (IEnumerable<dynamic>)member.AgentsByUri
         where agent.Name = "AgentsByUri"  // this line may be redundant
         from x in (IEnumerable<dynamic>)agent.Value
         select x.AbsoluteUri).Contains("SomeValue")
    select member.Value;
```

EDIT: The suggestion in my second comment does not quite work. I changed the code in LINQ syntax above to account for dynamic objects as the source by explicitly casting to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. Note however that the cast will fail for an enumeration of a value type.
I hope this will work for you.

Comment: Try `.Cast<dynamic>()`

Comment: Getting somewhere with this! See EDIT3

Comment: This looks interesting, I just don't quite follow it :) - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/FreeBookArticles/AddisonWesley/2010Feb02225705PM/Csharp4Features/7.aspx

Comment: You would have to apply it to every dynamic object, presumably member, agent and x.
Btw. explicitly specifying the type as dynamic. e.g. `from dynamic member in g.Members`is equivalent to `from member in g.Members.Cast<dynamic>()`

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give a proper answer without having a proper overview of the class structure. I guess this might work:

```
var uri = CsQ.Groups.SelectMany(g => g.Members).Where(a => a.Name == "AgentsByUri").Select(b => b.Value).Where(x => x.AbsoluteUri == "SomeValue");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do some digging and make a few assumptions here:

1. You want to return a list of PSMemberInfo.
2. PsMemberInfo.Name must equal "AgentsByUri".
3. In the Value property (which is a collection of Uri), you want to filter this collection on items whose AbsoluteUri property equals "SomeValue".

```cs
var we = CsQ.Groups.SelectMany(g => g.Members).Where(member => member.Name == "AgentsByUri" && member.Value != null && member.Value.Any(uri => uri.AbsoluteUri == "SomeValue")).ToList();
```